# Why do my container elements shift vertically when the content of a child element overflows its horizontal bounds?

Tags: html, css

jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/9vrytfs3/

I'm in the early stages of designing a control panel.  Each button on the panel should be of a fixed width and height.

A little bit of CSS takes care of that:

```
    .item {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color:#eee;
        color: #000;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .item-label {
        width: 140px;
        margin:5px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align:center;

    }
```

When text is entered into an `.item-label` that overflows it's horizontal bounds (width) causing word-wrap to engage... and the enclosing `.item` (`#item1`) is positioned next to another `.item` (`#item2`) whose `.item-label` does not overflow its horizontal bounds, then `#item2` gets translated in the positive Y-axis.

Put another way:  When an `.item` with a long title sits next to an `.item` with a short title, the item with the short title gets shifted downward on screen.

This is very much not wanted.  All `.item`s in a single "row" should align their tops visually.

In my testing, this happens on Windows for Chrome 71 (64 bit), Edge (42.17134), and IE 11.112

What is causing this?  Or how can I fix this?

Happy to provide more info if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Simply need `overflow: hidden`

```css
.item {
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background-color:#eee;
   color: #000;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }

  .item-label {
   width: 140px;
   margin:5px;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align:center;
      word-break: break-word;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<div class="">
   <h4>Site Administration</h4>
   <div class="section-items-container">
     
      <div class="item">
       <div class="item-label">Permissions</div>
      </div>
     
     
      <div class="item">
       <div class="item-label">Alternate Views</div>
      </div>
     
     
      <div class="item">
       <div class="item-label">Accrediting Bodies of Work</div>
      </div>
     
     
      <div class="item">
       <div class="item-label">Duplicate Users</div>
      </div>
     
     
      <div class="item">
       <div class="item-label">User Search</div>
      </div>
     
   </div>
  </div>
<div class="">
   <h4>Reports</h4>
   <div class="section-items-container">
   </div>
  </div>
<div class="">
   <h4>Developer Tools</h4>
   <div class="section-items-container">
     
      <div class="item">
       <div class="item-label">Registration Search Advanced</div>
      </div>
     
     
      <div class="item">
       <div class="item-label">Settings Cache</div>
      </div>
     
     
      <div class="item">
       <div class="item-label">Update Moodle Export</div>
      </div>
     
   </div>
  </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and why? ......

Comment: Because `inline-block` is treated as regular content, so it is affected by `line-height`. because all boxes had one line except there was issue with too long text which resulted in two lines. For this box `line-height` pushed the container to top. Overflow fixes it, but would be best to use flex grid anyway.

Comment: line-height has nothing to do here. The default alignment is `baseline` and adding overflow:hidden will make the baseline of inline-block to be the bottom of it and no more its text content and since all have the same height they will get aligned right ... the best whould be to simply set `vertical-align:top` instead of overflow (this solution will fail if the elements don't have the same height: https://jsfiddle.net/4kq3tcdy/)

Comment: @Trouble: Thanks for the comment.  In what way would flex grid be best?  What would one gain by using flex grid over the method I'm currently using?